# Cassandra result from running query cqlsh from one of the node cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra and haven't finished read the doc yet.
Just want to know if I run cqlsh from one node of a 3 nodes cluster and run query
e.g.

```
cqlsh node1host -u username -p passwd -k my_cass_keyspace
> select ...
```

is the result come from all the 3 nodes or it is just result from the node that I run cqsh in?
Sorry for very noob question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

General answer : from all node.

Detailed answer : 
Your node might be the coordinator, then depending on your replication factor, the node might fetch data from other nodes ( for example RF 1, then you query on a partition from another node).

This depends on your replication factor, and also your consistency level. 
you can check your consistency when using cqlsh by (default is ONE) :

```
cqlsh> consistency;
Current consistency level is ONE.
```

You can change it by ( to QUORUM for example) :

```
cqlsh> CONSISTENCY QUORUM ;
```

If you want to know details about your request execution plan, try to activate tracing :

```
cqlsh> tracing on ;
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes, it comes from all the nodes but it depends upon you cluster configurations, replication factor and consistency level.

For Example:- You have 3 nodes cluster and replication factor is 3 and consistency level is quorum for read and write both so whenever you will do insert query then your data will replicate to all 3 nodes but 2 nodes acknowledgement is sufficient to coordinator as quorum. same fill follow if you do a select query.

You may also refer Cassandra documentation as below:-
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/architecture/dynamo.html#replication